# Could you apply a CC-BY license to a piece of land?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

Suppose you are a land owner. You own a large piece of land containing lots of amazing fossils and other important pieces of history. To share this with the world you decide you want to allow ANYONE to come and discover the history on your property.

**My question:**

#### EDIT

Could you apply an open source license such as CC-BY to all of the artifacts they find in the property.

Comment: Why would licensing affect someone's ability to visit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't fork land, you can't derive it or even copy it.

The answer is no, you can only normally license something that is your own creation, and land belongs to that of mother nature.

Answer (score 8):

No.

A piece of land is not a creative work. People can't copy it. It has nothing to do with licenses to copyrighted works.